# 'Submit' Button click causes postback on first click and submits on the second click

Tags: javascript, button, click, postback

I have two buttons on the web page. The web page displays a pdf form that has several fields with validations. By validations I mean some are mandatory fields and some are conditional.
if all these validations are done succesfully then you can submit the pdf form.

PROBLEM:
I enter few fields, click on save, it saves the data. next I click on submit it prompts me to fill all other fields and submit is disabled which is correct. Now, I fill all other fields and click on save. Submit button is enabled. I click on submit button, it causes a postback and reloads the page. I again click on submit button, this time it goes and submits the form.

Why is postback happening on first click? and why does it submits on second click.

the method it should call on the click of submit button is a javascript function.

any help would be appreciated. I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Code or a URL would be useful

Answer (score 1):

You should add onclick="return false;" to avoid the postback.